# Why are my floated elements displaying like "stairs"?

Tags: html, css

I have 10 squares that are floated, and in a wrapper. I wrap each square in an anchor tag so that I can link the squares.

So I have a wrapper and inside I have 10 of these elements:

```css
.square {
  float: left;
  width: calc(20% - 16px);
  padding-bottom: calc(20% - 16px);
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(myimg.jpg);
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 8px;
  transition: ease all .3s;
  color: rgb(255, 230, 20);
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 88%;
  height: 89%;
  top: 6%;
  left: 6%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="productsWrap">
  <a href="mylink.com">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="content content1">
        <span class="squareTitle">Bending</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
  //and then ten more of the same anchor tags
</div>
```

The first 5 squares display like stairs, and the five remaining that are in the second row display properly inline.

Comment: Please include enough code to reproduce the issue. If you are asking about the behavior of 10 elements, we need to see those 10 elements.

Comment: tell me what you exactly want to do ..?

Comment: float the anchor, not the square

Comment: @TylerH It's just 10 of the exact same element. I didn't think it was necessary to write it out 10 times and take up a page of space.

Comment: @AndrewMcCracken See [mcve] for more info; page space or no, we need to see the code because we can't assume what your code may be. If it really is so long (10 spans is nothing, space-wise), the built-in stack snippet feature that I edited your code into earlier has an option to hide/minimize the code by default and expand on click.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are floating .square element but expecting .content to be floating. Here is the answer:

**Improved HTML**

```
<div class="productsWrap">
  <div class="square">
    <a href="mylink.com">
      <div class="content content1">
        <span class="squareTitle">Bending</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <a href="mylink.com">
      <div class="content content1">
        <span class="squareTitle">Bending</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <a href="mylink.com">
      <div class="content content1">
        <span class="squareTitle">Bending</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <a href="mylink.com">
      <div class="content content1">
        <span class="squareTitle">Bending</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <a href="mylink.com">
      <div class="content content1">
        <span class="squareTitle">Bending</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <a href="mylink.com">
      <div class="content content1">
        <span class="squareTitle">Bending</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <a href="mylink.com">
      <div class="content content1">
        <span class="squareTitle">Bending</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <a href="mylink.com">
      <div class="content content1">
        <span class="squareTitle">Bending</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <a href="mylink.com">
      <div class="content content1">
        <span class="squareTitle">Bending</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="square">
    <a href="mylink.com">
      <div class="content content1">
        <span class="squareTitle">Bending</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Improved CSS**

```
.square {
  float: left;
  width: calc(20% - 16px);
  padding-bottom: calc(20% - 16px);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f00;
  border-radius: 5%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 8px;
  transition: ease all .3s;
  color: rgb(255, 230, 20);
}

.square a {
  color:yellow;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 88%;
  height: 89%;
  top: 6%;
  left: 6%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

**And Here is the result**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZv8B.jpg)